# Cordova get device display density

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am developing a hybrid app using cordova. Is there any way to get the device display information such as density and screen resolution? From there I can calculate the device screen size.

Comment: Google [CSS Media Query](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+media+query)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Do you mean we can get the device density (PPI) via CSS Media Query?

Comment: Okay, I can see the confusion. You will want to read this essay - [A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](https://web.archive.org/web/20150816014632/http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) He talks about media query near the end, but the rest is very important.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Thanks for the link. I just wish to get the device density (PPI). Is it possible to get it?

Comment: yes you can, but it defeats one of the reason for Phonegap. Phonegap is trying to be agnostic. And as PPK said, 99% of all developers don't know or care about PPI.  For this task, you should look for a plugin. The best place to look is this [search engine](http://plugins.cordova.io/npm/index.html?q=). You can also ask your question at [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) and [Nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi). Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is a late answer but perhaps it may help someone else. I've only come upon one Cordova plugin that purports to provide density information:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screensize

Not tried it though so caveat emptor.